# Is there a way to re-orient normals?

Tags: normals

I need all my normals to be oriented in the same angle, but as you can see from my screenshot, the outer edge are turned one way and the inner edge are 90º offset, so I'm just wondering if there's a way to manually turn them?

[image]

Comment: Press `Ctrl`+`N` or use the operator `Flip Normals`

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos - I don't think that "flip normals" is what he means, although there isn't any other method to rearrange normals

Comment: Correct, I know how to flip normals, it's the rotation I was wanting to change so that the X and Y axes faced the same direction.

Comment: There is no other possibility to manipulate normals in blender than flipping them. Maybe you could explain a little more in detail what exactly your problem is?

Comment: Those are probably dependent on vertex indexes and resulting face drawing directions. As far as I know there is no direct way to control them, other than possibly manually redrawing the faces.

Comment: So no go then? Thanks anyway, guys. I needed them all the same direction so that my hair particles all lean the same direction, but it seems I'll have to find another way to do it. Combing is so inaccurate and time-consuming I was trying to find a short-cut where there obviously isn't one :)

Comment: An editing normals modifier was added to blender a couple of years ago but i found it too complicated to use.https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/modifiers/modify/normal_edit.html

Comment: An easier to use and perhaps more usefull tool can be found in the Blender4web Normal Editor addon https://www.blend4web.com/en/community/article/131/ where you can manually rotate vertex normals.

Comment: You could use particle system's settings In order to orient hair. E.g. to make them growing in the Z direction regardless normals set *Normal* in the Velocity rollout to 0 and set value of the Z axis under the same rollout > Emitter Object to something more than 0.

Answer (score 3):

By definition the [face normals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_(geometry)) are perpendicular to the face and can't be adjusted to a specific rotation.

To alter the way the hair is emitted, you want to use something other than the normals to determine the initial direction, you can adjust this in the particle settings.

Enable the advanced option which makes the velocity panel available for hair particles. Set the normal value to 0.0 and change the emitter object values to the direction you want the hair to go.

[image: particle options]

Answer (score 1):

You can use a different, invisible, flat panel to act as hair emitter

Answer (score 0):

The darker parts seem to have inward facing normals.
With these parts selected hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>. If that doesn't fix them <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> probably will.